# Error a sumar valores de un select en mysql

Tags: mysql

Mi código en `MYSQL` es:

```
SELECT COALESCE(payments.base,0) as total, count(*) 
FROM `payments` 
INNER JOIN `pagos` ON `pagos`.id = `payments`.pago_id 
INNER JOIN `documents` ON `documents`.id = `pagos`.document_id 
INNER JOIN `clients` ON `clients`.id = `documentos`.client_id 
WHERE (pagos.money=1 AND (clients.group_id = 14) AND (payments.deleted = 0)
GROUP BY payments.base
ORDER BY payments.base
```

El resultado que tengo es:

```
total  | count(*)
54.8   |  3
399.76 |  2
```

Lo que estoy necesitando es que se sume el grupo de `54.8 + 399.76` el `total = 454.56`.

¿Qué corrijo para obtener el resultado esperado?

Comment: No entiendo. ¿quieres un tercer registro con el total? ¿Quieres un solo registro con el total?

Comment: prueba con un `SUM(COALESCE(payments.base,0)) as total`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El resultado esperado no lo tengo muy claro. Te dejo una opción, y te tocará aclarar si no es lo que quisistes decir.

Si lo que quieres es que la consulta te devuelva un solo registro con el total de los grupos `54.8` y `399.76`, puedes lograrlo eliminando el `GROUP BY` (y el `ORDER BY`) y usando un `SUM(DISTINCT ...)`:

```
SELECT SUM(DISTINCT COALESCE(payments.base,0)) as total
FROM `payments` 
INNER JOIN `pagos` ON `pagos`.id = `payments`.pago_id 
INNER JOIN `documents` ON `documents`.id = `pagos`.document_id 
INNER JOIN `clients` ON `clients`.id = `documentos`.client_id 
WHERE (pagos.money=1 AND (clients.group_id = 14) AND (payments.deleted = 0)
```

Comment: Gracias sstan fue de gran ayuda!!